# Merging 2 tables with ids that overlap

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I have 2 tables, their structure is identical but used to serve in 2 different applications. So, each of them have unique records (records from app1 won't exist in app2). But their Ids are maintained separately by the 2 apps. So, ids from app1 might exist in app2 but with different information.

I need to merge these 2 tables records into one table because the 2 applications are being merged into one. The problem is with the ids. I will probably reset the ids and regenerate the unique id for each record. The ids is not referenced by other tables, so resetting it is not a problem. But I'm not really sure how to execute this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a table with an auto incremend (id) column.

Then create an INSERT ... SELECT query to import data from each table

Eg

```
INSERT INTO new_table(column1,column2,.....) -- ommiting the id column
SELECT column1,column2,... -- ommiting the id column
FROM old_table1

INSERT INTO new_table(column1,column2,.....) -- ommiting the id column
SELECT column1,column2,...-- ommiting the id column
FROM old_table2
```

Comment: It might even work with `CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM old_tabe1`, and then the second `INSERT` statement. It depends on the current structure of `old_table1`/`old_table2`.

Comment: @MizardX you are right. He can also keep one table, and import data from the other :)

Comment: @Phelios: Since the ids are not referenced by other tables, it's a rather easy job and can be it done in many ways. If you want to have that old ids stored, don't omit that column (and don't make it unique).

Comment: @Phelios: I meant to have a new `id` as primary key, auto incremented, as niktrs' suggestion and keep another column (`old_id`) with the old ids, if you need them off course.

Answer (score 1):

The `INSERT INTO  .. SELECT FROM` is to be used here - without the `id` column. Aslo, I would put an application_id column into the new table - just to be sure that I know what data came from where:

```
INSERT INTO your_table(app_id, col1,co2,.....) 
SELECT 1, col1,col2,... 
FROM old_table1
```

For application 2:

```
INSERT INTO your_table(app_id, col1,co2,.....) 
SELECT 2, col1,col2,... 
FROM old_table2
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, ids from app1 might exist in app2
>   but with different information.

One option you may want to  look into is [using a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/views.html) to consolidate the data of both tables in a format acceptable for whatever application.